# Not sure why path only exists for portion of while-loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, os.path

At a certain point in my while loop I run os.listdir on a three item index to generate a list of files and I get "Windows Error 3 - Path doesn't exist" even though I have called this path previously in my script successfully.

I ran an os.path.exists on it after and it says that for the first two loops the directory evaluates as False but on the third it evaluates as True.

I've tried using glob.glob and that also only returns files on the third loop.

The trouble is in the while loop under the "creates Read nodes based on number of shots found" comment.

Any help to have to read it as True from the beginning would be appreciated, thanks!

```
# Iterating using while loop, this gets every version folder for each shots' plates and stores to a "version" list 

while shotIndex < shotAmountTotal: 
    nextShot = (shots[shotIndex]) 
    shotIndex += 1
    verSearchPath = shotSearchPath + '/' + nextShot + '/' + compFolder + '/' + platesFolder
    foundVerList = os.listdir(verSearchPath)
    verListCombined.append(foundVerList)
    verListSorted = list(chain.from_iterable(verListCombined))



#this groups the like folder names, splits them at the underscore before the version number and then returns only the highest version number of each group

    groupedShotFolders = groupby(verListSorted, key=lambda version: version.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
    latestShotVer = [sorted(group, reverse=True)[0] for key, group in groupedShotFolders]


#creates Read nodes based on number of shots found

latestShotAmount = len(latestShotVer)
latestShotIndex = 0

while latestShotIndex < latestShotAmount:
    latestShot = (latestShotVer[latestShotIndex])
    frameListerPath = verSearchPath + '/' + latestShot + '/' + fileExtension + '/'
    print os.path.exists(frameListerPath)        

    frameLister = os.listdir(verSearchPath + '/' + latestShot + '/' + fileExtension + '/')
```

The terminal output I am getting is:

```
Result: False
E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_010_BG_001_v002/exr/
[]
False
E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_010_FG_001_v003/exr/
[]
True
E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003/exr/
['E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003/exr\\MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003.0999.exr', 'E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003/exr\\MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003.1000.exr', 'E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003/exr\\MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003.1001.exr', 'E:/projects/MBR/shots/103/MRS_103_005_020/2d/plates/MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003/exr\\MRS_103_005_020_BG_001_v003.1002.exr']
```

Comment: Could it be that the last / is to much? Seems a bit weird to have a slash after the fileExtension

Comment: You should use `os.path.join()` rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: @Barmar could you please provide an example of how I would use that? 

Could I do:

frameListerJoined = os.path.join(frameListerPath) 
frameLister = os.listdir(frameListerJoined) ?

Comment: `verSearchPath = os.path.join(shotSearchPath, nextShot, compFolder, platesFolder)`

Comment: @Syrius if I remove the extra slash it doesn't find anything at all on the third loop.

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate the best practices suggestion but that doesn't change what the loop is doing. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't intended as a solution for the problem. That's why it was just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Try printing your paths so you can see what name it's complaining about when it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Another best practice: `for latestShot in latestShotVer:`

Comment: Please don't take my comment as a dismissal. I am very new to coding and this site.

Could I also please ask you how you would integrate the for loop within the existing code? I will update the main post with the path, True/False, and file output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to chalk this one up to user error. Firstly I switched to the "for" and "join" methods to clean things up a bit. Next it turns out that the "nextShot" variable in my previous code wasn't iterating properly so it only output the last item of the iteration which is why the first two paths evaluated to False.  I fixed this by putting the "latestShot" variable in its place and trimming off the descriptors.

To avoid the double-slashing that happens with the "os.listdir" I split it out and rejoined with forwardslashes.

Thanks for your thoughts and guidance on this.

```
for latestShot in latestShotVer:
    nuke.createNode("Read", inpanel = False)
    frameListerPath = os.path.join(shotSearchPath, latestShot[:-12], compFolder, platesFolder, latestShot, fileExtension)
    flsplit = frameListerPath.split('\\')
    fljoin = '/'.join(flsplit)
    frameListerPath = fljoin
    frameLister = os.listdir(frameListerPath)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity--it's not really clear from your original question what exactly it is that you are trying to do. I.e. what exact is the directory/file structure you are expecting, and given a conforming directory structure what is the output you're trying to obtain exactly? I have a suspicion there's a simpler way to do, well, whatever you're doing. But as it is the question is unlikely to be interesting to future readers.